# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2y-x$ using method of successive approximations where $\phi(0) =0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, fixed-point-theorems

I want to find the general expression for '''phi n(x) but the only way I can do that is by using an iterative product. Is there a better way to do it? Also i want to show that the sequence {\phi n(x)} converges.

Comment: Hi, welcome to MathStack  please check this post on [how to ask good questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
Could you provide some context to your question? What is the function $\phi$? Did you meant $\phi_n(x)$ or $\phi^n(x)$ and how are they defined?
And please, also include what have you tried so far in the post.
Also, might be relevant to look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582540/solve-y-y-y0-1-using-method-of-successive-approximations-obtaining-the?rq=1

Comment: Assume the function is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, and use the differential equation to form a recurrence relation for the $a_n$. Solve the recurrence.